# How do I combine hierarchical data in pandas using a multiindex without duplicating the rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say I have 3 datasets `A`, `B`, and `C` with hierarchical keys `[primary]`, `[primary, secondary]`, `[primary, secondary, tertiary]`.   Is there a way I can group them all into a single multiindexexd dataframe with 3 levels for data transformation but register that variables from dataset `A` only exist at the `[primary]` level and variables from dataset `B` only exist at `[primary, secondary]` level?

My solution so far for transformations is to outer merge `A`, `B`, and `C` which duplicates the values to lower "key levels" in the hierarchy.  This does allow me to reference a groupby/slice at the appropriate level every time I want to use the variable from datasets `A` or `B`, but this feels sub-optimal especially in terms of memory usage if there are many `[secondary,teritary]` keys that I need to duplicate every single column of `A` over. It also imposes a burden on me to remember which columns belong to which dataset so I don't accidentally edit only a subset of the keys when trying to change all values on `A`

As a concrete example of what im looking for: I want a dataframe where columns `A1` from `A` are stored at `[primary]` index and `B1` from `B` are stored at [primary, secondary] multiindex in a memory efficient way where I can reference both columns when performing transformations like below, where pandas can be smart enough to look up `A1` value at multiindexindex of `(5)` when adding to `C1` of `(5,1,1)` instead of having to duplicate `A1` values across `(5, :, :)`.

```
df.loc[filter, "A1"] = df["A1"] + df["C1"]
```

If I cant get that, a way to make those duplicates of `A` variables pointers so changing one of them changes all of them would be great. I want this in a single df object that I can apply many data transformation steps to.  I would prefer to do this in pandas but I will accept non-pandas solutions as well.

The following is provided as a MRE. The one thing not shown is that I can have keys in the higher level dataframe that dont exist in the lower levels.  so A can have (1,1), (1,2) while B only has (1,2,1) and (1,2,2), making the 3rd level of the merge technically NaN if I didn't exclude those cases and treat them separately.  It would be nice if the multiindex could support "nulls" such as `(1,5,nan)` or just `(1,5)` if no `tertiary` keys existed on dataset `C` for that observation. Note the `wanted` df below is fine if it looks the same as "after" example, as long as vars are optimized so its not copied uselessly.

```
import pandas as pd
d= {'C1': {(1, 1, 1): 32, (1, 1, 2): 30, (1, 1, 3): 32, (1, 1, 4): 35, (1, 2, 1): 36, (1, 2, 2): 37, (2, 1, 1): 33, (2, 1, 2): 40, (2, 2, 1): 32, (3, 1, 1): 32, (3, 2, 1): 36, (3, 2, 2): 31, (3, 2, 3): 33, (3, 2, 4): 38, (4, 1, 1): 34, (4, 1, 2): 30, (4, 2, 1): 31}, 'C2': {(1, 1, 1): 40, (1, 1, 2): 37, (1, 1, 3): 37, (1, 1, 4): 30, (1, 2, 1): 37, (1, 2, 2): 35, (2, 1, 1): 30, (2, 1, 2): 32, (2, 2, 1): 33, (3, 1, 1): 38, (3, 2, 1): 30, (3, 2, 2): 35, (3, 2, 3): 31, (3, 2, 4): 36, (4, 1, 1): 33, (4, 1, 2): 32, (4, 2, 1): 36}, 'B1': {(1, 1, 1): 17, (1, 1, 2): 17, (1, 1, 3): 17, (1, 1, 4): 17, (1, 2, 1): 18, (1, 2, 2): 18, (2, 1, 1): 11, (2, 1, 2): 11, (2, 2, 1): 12, (3, 1, 1): 15, (3, 2, 1): 18, (3, 2, 2): 18, (3, 2, 3): 18, (3, 2, 4): 18, (4, 1, 1): 19, (4, 1, 2): 19, (4, 2, 1): 15}, 'B2': {(1, 1, 1): 16, (1, 1, 2): 16, (1, 1, 3): 16, (1, 1, 4): 16, (1, 2, 1): 15, (1, 2, 2): 15, (2, 1, 1): 10, (2, 1, 2): 10, (2, 2, 1): 14, (3, 1, 1): 11, (3, 2, 1): 14, (3, 2, 2): 14, (3, 2, 3): 14, (3, 2, 4): 14, (4, 1, 1): 11, (4, 1, 2): 11, (4, 2, 1): 19}, 'A1': {(1, 1, 1): 9, (1, 1, 2): 9, (1, 1, 3): 9, (1, 1, 4): 9, (1, 2, 1): 9, (1, 2, 2): 9, (2, 1, 1): 8, (2, 1, 2): 8, (2, 2, 1): 8, (3, 1, 1): 5, (3, 2, 1): 5, (3, 2, 2): 5, (3, 2, 3): 5, (3, 2, 4): 5, (4, 1, 1): 4, (4, 1, 2): 4, (4, 2, 1): 4}, 'A2': {(1, 1, 1): 3, (1, 1, 2): 3, (1, 1, 3): 3, (1, 1, 4): 3, (1, 2, 1): 3, (1, 2, 2): 3, (2, 1, 1): 3, (2, 1, 2): 3, (2, 2, 1): 3, (3, 1, 1): 8, (3, 2, 1): 8, (3, 2, 2): 8, (3, 2, 3): 8, (3, 2, 4): 8, (4, 1, 1): 5, (4, 1, 2): 5, (4, 2, 1): 5}}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
print("Before:\n",df)
df.loc[filter, "C1"] = df["A1"] + df["C1"]
print("After\n",df)
```

output:

```
Before:
        C1  C2  B1  B2  A1  A2
1 1 1  32  40  17  16   9   3
    2  30  37  17  16   9   3
    3  32  37  17  16   9   3
    4  35  30  17  16   9   3
  2 1  36  37  18  15   9   3
    2  37  35  18  15   9   3
2 1 1  33  30  11  10   8   3
    2  40  32  11  10   8   3
  2 1  32  33  12  14   8   3
3 1 1  32  38  15  11   5   8
  2 1  36  30  18  14   5   8
    2  31  35  18  14   5   8
    3  33  31  18  14   5   8
    4  38  36  18  14   5   8
4 1 1  34  33  19  11   4   5
    2  30  32  19  11   4   5
  2 1  31  36  15  19   4   5
After
        C1  C2  B1  B2  A1  A2
1 1 1  41  40  17  16   9   3
    2  30  37  17  16   9   3
    3  41  37  17  16   9   3
    4  44  30  17  16   9   3
  2 1  45  37  18  15   9   3
    2  46  35  18  15   9   3
2 1 1  41  30  11  10   8   3
    2  48  32  11  10   8   3
  2 1  40  33  12  14   8   3
3 1 1  37  38  15  11   5   8
  2 1  41  30  18  14   5   8
    2  31  35  18  14   5   8
    3  38  31  18  14   5   8
    4  43  36  18  14   5   8
4 1 1  38  33  19  11   4   5
    2  30  32  19  11   4   5
  2 1  31  36  15  19   4   5
Wanted 
        C1  C2  B1  B2  A1  A2
1 1 1  41  40  17  16   9   3
    2  30  37                
    3  41  37                
    4  44  30                
  2 1  45  37  18  15   9   3
    2  46  35                
2 1 1  41  30  11  10   8   3
    2  48  32                
  2 1  40  33  12  14        
3 1 1  37  38  15  11   5   8
  2 1  41  30  18  14        
    2  31  35                
    3  38  31                
    4  43  36                
4 1 1  38  33  19  11   4   5
    2  30  32                
  2 1  31  36  15  19
```